# Construction of a partition of unity by Warner

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I'm reading the proof on the existence of a partition of unity, given by Warner. The proof is constructive, and to start it, he chose a coordinate system $(V,\tau)$ on which many restrictions are imposed:

[image]

I feel awkward about such an artificial setting. Is it always possible to make $\tau$ centered at a specific point? Is it always can be done to restrict $V$ within a certain set? To make our discussion efficient, some terminologies are given as follows.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. The general situation is that you have $p\in M$ and an open neigborhood $W$ of $p$. The claim is that there exists a coordinate system ($V,\tau)$ centered at $p$ such that $V \subset W$ and $\overline{C(2)} \subset \tau(V)$.

Take any coordinate system $(U,\varphi)$ in $\mathcal F$ such that $p \in U$. The map $\varphi : U \to U'$ is a homeomorphism onto an open $U' \subset \mathbb R^d$. Then also $(U \cap W, \psi : U \cap W \stackrel{\varphi}{\rightarrow} \varphi(U \cap W))$ is a coordinate system in $\mathcal F$ with $p \in U \cap W$. Thus we can assume w.l.o.g. that $U \subset W$.

Let $q = \varphi(p)$. The translation $T_q : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d, T_q(x) = x - q$, is a diffeomorphism and $(U,\varphi_q)$ with $\varphi_q : U \stackrel{\varphi}{\rightarrow} U' \stackrel{T_q}{\rightarrow} T_q(U')$ is a new coordinate system in $\mathcal F$ which satisfies $\varphi_q(p) = 0$. Since $T_q(U')$ is an open neighborhood of $0$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $\overline{C(r)} \subset T_q(U')$. The map $S_r : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d, S_r(x) = \frac{2}{r}x$, is a diffeomorphism such that $S_r(\overline{C(r)}) = \overline{C(2)}$. Now define
$\tau : U \stackrel{\varphi_q}{\rightarrow} T_q(U') \stackrel{S_r}{\rightarrow} S_r(T_q(U'))$. Then $(U,\tau) \in \mathcal F$.

What is done here is something like "norming" coordinate systems $(U,\varphi)$ with $p \in U$ with respect to their range $U' =\varphi(U)$. In fact you may achieve that $\varphi(p)$ is any prescribed point $q \in \mathbb R^d$ and that $U'$ is any prescribed open neighborhood of $q$. Frequently one takes $q = 0$ and $U' = \mathbb R^d$ or $U' =$ open unit ball etc.

Comment: Sir, I have one question. In the second paragraph, how did you know $\psi$ has a continuous inverse?

Comment: If you have a homeomorphism $f : A \to B$, then for any $A' \subset A$ the restriction $f' : A' \to f(A')$ of $f$ is also a homeomorphism. Its inverse is the restriction of $f^{-1} : B \to A$ to $f(A')$ whose image under $f^{-1}$ is $f^{-1}(f(A')) = A'$. By the way, you need not use the formal "Sir" in this forum ;-)

Comment: Is $\overline{C(r)}$ built by first finding an open ball that is contained in $T_q(U')$?

Comment: Another question: If the map in a coordinate system is simply homeomorphic, then why did Warner claim that $\psi_p\in C^\infty$ (defined below the part circled in red ink)? Thank you.

Comment: First question: It is a well-known fact that all norms on $\mathbb R^d$ generate the same topology on $\mathbb R^d$ (i.e. produce the same open sets). The open $r$-cubes $C(s)$ are the open $s$-neighborhoods of $0$ with respect to $\lVert(x_1,\dots,x_d)\rVert = \max_i(\lvert x_i \rvert)$. Now note that for $r < s$ we have $\overline{C(r)} \subset C(s)$. But if you want you can also take an open ball contained in $T_q(U')$ and then inscribe a closed cube $\overline{C(r)} $.

Comment: Second question: It is not explictly mentioned in the book that $(U,\tau) \in \mathcal F$, but our construction gives evidence that it can be chosen to be. In your sreenshot one can neither see what $\varphi$ is nor that is claimed that $\psi_p$ is $C^\infty$. So I suggest you ask another question making these issues precise.